# How can i convert a JSON array payload into one object with specific fields and an array with dates?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JSON payload fetched from the backend. The data contains an `payload` array with objects. By some how i want to convert these objects inside the array to one object, and the `selectedDate` dates to own array. The JSON payload seems like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"payload": [
    {
        "weekNumber": 40,
        "sortOrder": 1,
        "label": "autumn",
        "numberOfPossibleDays": 3,
        "editable": true,
        "selectedDate": "2020-09-29",
        "deliveryDays": [
            {
                "date": "2020-09-28",
                "contactPerson": null,
                "phoneNumber": null,
                "contactPerson2": null,
                "phoneNumber2": null,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-09-29",
                "contactPerson": "John",
                "phoneNumber": "99887744",
                "contactPerson2": "Tom",
                "phoneNumber2": "40040000,
                "selected": true
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-09-30",
                "contactPerson": null,
                "phoneNumber": null,
                "contactPerson2": null,
                "phoneNumber2": null,
                "selected": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "weekNumber": 53,
        "sortOrder": 2,
        "label": "christmas",
        "numberOfPossibleDays": 2,
        "editable": true,
        "selectedDate": "2020-12-29",
        "deliveryDays": [
            {
                "date": "2020-12-28",
                "contactPerson": null,
                "phoneNumber": null,
                "contactPerson2": null,
                "phoneNumber2": null,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-12-29",
                "contactPerson": "Doe,
                "phoneNumber": "99999999",
                "contactPerson2": "Foo",
                "phoneNumber2": "44552200",
                "selected": true
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What i want to do is to get output objects like this:

```
{
    autumn=firstContactPersonName: "John",
    autumn=firstContactPersonPhone: "46442644",
    autumn=secondContactPersonName: "Tom",
    autumn=secondContactPersonPhone: "40040000"
    christmas=firstContactPersonName: "Doe",
    christmas=firstContactPersonPhone: "99999999",
    christmas=secondContactPersonName: "Foo",
    christmas=secondContactPersonPhone: "44552200"
}
```

And the dates output should be an array like this:

```
const dateArray = ["autumn=2020-09-29", "christmas=2020-12-29"]
```

I want it to be dynamically, because sometimes i might be have a object for `easter` and so on. Why i want to do this is because I am using the object to populate content in the input fields and the `dateArray` to enable which dates is choosen. I know this is not the best solution, but i have to try to make it out this way.
I am all new to JavaScript and i have some problems making it out. I would appreciate if anyone can help me out, please? I hope the question and the example is good. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What's the problem with the original format? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve by doing this strange conversion. I think you will find it doesn't help you in the end. "I am using the object to implement the input fields" is a bit vague...can you show precisely what kind of output you want from the sample data (in terms of fields generated)? There is almost certainly a better way to do it.

Comment: I want to convert the JSON payload into the object and array as output. If you understand what i mean? I can edit the question.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I just don't understand **why** you would want to put the data in such a bad format. That's why I asked you to show us what the end result should be - you mentioned "I am using the object to implement the input fields and the dateArray to enable which dates is choosen"... so I am asking you to show us what input fields and date fields you are trying to create, based on this data. Then we can help you find a better way to do it.

Comment: (This is one of those questions which smells like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/), which is why I'm asking.)

Comment: I dont want to create InputFields based on this. I want to use the object to populate content inside the each input fields in my form. And each input fields have a name `seasonName=firstContactPersonName` and so on.

Comment: Ok well, still, it's nearly the same thing so please show a few examples of the input fields, so we can help you. Almost certainly, converting your data into your requested format will not be useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
    let obj = {
    "success": true,
    "payload": [
        {
            "weekNumber": 40,
            "sortOrder": 1,
            "label": "autumn",
            "numberOfPossibleDays": 3,
            "editable": true,
            "selectedDate": "2020-09-29",
            "deliveryDays": [
                {
                    "date": "2020-09-28",
                    "contactPerson": null,
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "contactPerson2": null,
                    "phoneNumber2": null,
                    "selected": false
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-09-29",
                    "contactPerson": "John",
                    "phoneNumber": "99887744",
                    "contactPerson2": "Tom",
                    "phoneNumber2": "40040000",
                    "selected": true
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-09-30",
                    "contactPerson": null,
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "contactPerson2": null,
                    "phoneNumber2": null,
                    "selected": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "weekNumber": 53,
            "sortOrder": 2,
            "label": "christmas",
            "numberOfPossibleDays": 2,
            "editable": true,
            "selectedDate": "2020-12-29",
            "deliveryDays": [
                {
                    "date": "2020-12-28",
                    "contactPerson": null,
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "contactPerson2": null,
                    "phoneNumber2": null,
                    "selected": false
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-12-29",
                    "contactPerson": "Doe",
                    "phoneNumber": "99999999",
                    "contactPerson2": "Foo",
                    "phoneNumber2": "44552200",
                    "selected": true
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
    }

let results={};
let datesArray=[];
obj.payload.map((x)=>{
datesArray.push(x.label+"="+x.selectedDate);
  x["deliveryDays"].map((y)=>{
    if(y.contactPerson){
      let personKey = x.label + "=firstContactPersonName";
      results[personKey] = y.contactPerson;
      let contactKey = x.label+"=firstContactPersonPhone";
      results[contactKey] = y.phoneNumber;
    }
    if(y.contactPerson2){
      let secondPersonKey = x.label + "=secondContactPersonName";
      results[secondPersonKey] = y.contactPerson2;
      let secondContactKey = x.label+"=secondContactPersonPhone";
      results[secondContactKey] = y.phoneNumber2;
    }
  });

});

console.log(datesArray)
console.log(results)
```

We iterate throught payload and make use of dates array to store the dates and results array to obtain the first and second contact person names during a season. Hope this helps!